# 2020-09-01 - 2020-08-31 = 70 days

Tags: mysql, date

Did I do something wrong or this is a general error? I tried this query on 2 servers and both got 70 in return:

```
SELECT DATE('2020-09-01')-DATE('2020-08-31')
```

I thought I should get 1 in return instead of 70.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: While using in numeric context the server converts the date to YYYYMMDD format and then treates them as integers. 20200901 - 20200831 = 70, everything is correct.

Comment: @Akina It all make sense now. Thank you for a clear explanation. Would you post it as an answer? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function, eg:

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2020-09-01', '2020-08-31');
+--------------------------------------+
| DATEDIFF('2020-09-01', '2020-08-31') |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    1 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: ... or TIMESTAMPDIFF. The latter may be more safe when operands have time part and the amount of 24h-ranges is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to calculate the difference in days, use:

```
SELECT datediff('2020-09-01', '2020-08-31') as 'days'
```